# Custom spring filter not getting called when web application is accessed or url is hit

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Below is my configuration in web.xml and I have one JwtFilter but it is not getting access when rest urls are been called.

web.xml

```
<web-app
<display-name>Portal Web</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet-spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.pingle.lola.authentication.JwtFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/portal/lola/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my JwtFilter

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                     final ServletResponse res,
                     final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    System.out.println("came here");
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    System.out.println("came here - " + authHeader);
    if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        System.out.println("should throw");
        throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header.");
    }

    final String token = authHeader.substring(7); // The part after "Bearer "
    System.out.println("came here" + token);

    try {
        final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
    }
    catch (final SignatureException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Invalid token.");
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

}

and I have controller where basic rest API are confugured. I am trying to check if any URL is hit like localhost:8080/portal/lola/getData .. it should go to JwtFilter and check for authentication token in header of request and if valid pass it on the controller other wise throw error message. Logic is written properly but filter is not called and when I hit above URL, it goes to controller directly without reaching filter.

my spring config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pingle.lola.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

//Dont know why I created it when its not mapped to any controller :(

```
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `/portal` is name of application context. Filter url-pattern should not contain name of context. This means, that filter url-pattern should be `/lola/*` without `/portal`. Try to change filter mapping to:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/lola/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```